# How to use $hint in MongoDB aggregation query?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am using mongo v3.0.1 on a ubuntu machine. And I have a collection of 300million rows. I have created two indexes based on my query preference.

When I am trying to run aggregation with explain, It is taking the inefficient index, and that is why it's taking 20-25 secs more time. Is there any way to put `$hint`, so that my aggregation query use the appropriate  index.

`$match` is in my first pipeline stage. I have two indexes:

1. "Host_-1_SiteType_-1"
2. "VisitTime_-1_AccountId_-1_Host_-1_SiteType_-1_Extension_-1_LifeTime_-1"

and my `$match` pipeline is like :

```js
{ "$match" : {
    "AccountId": accID, 
    "VisitTime": { "$lte" : today, "$gte" : last365Days },
    "$or": [
        { "$and": [
            { "Extension":{ "$in": ["chrome_0","firefox_0"] }},
            { "LifeTime": 0 }
        ]},
        {  "LifeTime": { "$gt": 1000 }}
    ],
    "Host": { "$ne": "localhost" },
    "SiteType" : { "$exists": true },
}
```

and it is using first index, instead of second index. and the time taken by the first index in 50 secs where as using second index only it is taking only 18 secs.

Here is my one of the document sample:

```js
{ 
    "_id" : "2bc1143c-07e4-4c37-a020-a7485b2802a3", 
    "CreatedDate" : ISODate("2015-07-22T04:05:06.802+0000"), 
    "UpdatedDate" : ISODate("2015-07-22T05:28:26.469+0000"), 
    "AccountId" : accID, 
    "Url" : "http://www.test.com/test.html", 
    "Host" : "test.com", 
    "VisitTime" : ISODate("2014-08-12T18:08:25.813+0000"), 
    "LifeTime" : 789546.01, 
    "Status" : "closed", 
    "LocalTime" : ISODate("2014-08-12T18:08:25.813+0000"), 
    "DeviceId" : "123456789", 
    "Extension" : "firefox_0", 
    "SubSiteType" : "TestSubSite", 
    "SiteType" : "TestSite", 
    "Flag" : "1"
}
```

and here is my aggregation explanation:

```js
{
    "stages" : [
        {
            "$cursor" : {
                "query" : {
                    "AccountId" : "accID",
                    "VisitTime" : {
                        "$lte" : "2015-07-25T18:30:00Z",
                        "$gte" : "2014-07-25T18:30:00Z"
                    },
                    "Host" : {
                        "$ne" : "localhost"
                    },
                    "SiteType" : {
                        "$exists" : true
                    },
                    "$or" : [
                        {
                            "$and" : [
                                {
                                    "Extension" : {
                                        "$in" : [
                                            "chrome_0",
                                            "firefox_0"
                                        ]
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    "LifeTime" : 0
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "LifeTime" : {
                                "$gt" : 1000
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "fields" : {
                    "Host" : 1,
                    "_id" : 0
                },
                "queryPlanner" : {
                    "plannerVersion" : 1,
                    "namespace" : "Test",
                    "indexFilterSet" : false,
                    "parsedQuery" : {
                        "$and" : [
                            {
                                "$or" : [
                                    {
                                        "$and" : [
                                            {
                                                "LifeTime" : {
                                                    "$eq" : 0
                                                }
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "Extension" : {
                                                    "$in" : [
                                                        "chrome_0",
                                                        "firefox_0"
                                                    ]
                                                }
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "LifeTime" : {
                                            "$gt" : 1000
                                        }
                                    }
                                ]
                            },
                            {
                                "$not" : {
                                    "Host" : {
                                        "$eq" : "localhost"
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "VisitTime" : {
                                    "$lte" : "2015-07-25T18:30:00Z"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "AccountId" : {
                                    "$eq" : "accID"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "VisitTime" :"2014-07-25T18:30:00Z"

                            },
                            {
                                "SiteType" : {
                                    "$exists" : true
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    "winningPlan" : {
                        "stage" : "FETCH",
                        "filter" : {
                            "$and" : [
                                {
                                    "SiteType" : {
                                        "$exists" : true
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    "$or" : [
                                        {
                                            "$and" : [
                                                {
                                                    "LifeTime" : {
                                                        "$eq" : 0
                                                    }
                                                },
                                                {
                                                    "Extension" : {
                                                        "$in" : [
                                                            "chrome_0",
                                                            "firefox_0"
                                                        ]
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            ]
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "LifeTime" : {
                                                "$gt" : 1000
                                            }
                                        }
                                    ]
                                },
                                {
                                    "VisitTime" : {
                                        "$lte" : "2015-07-25T18:30:00Z"
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    "AccountId" : {
                                        "$eq" : "accID"
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    "VisitTime" : {
                                        "$gte" : "2014-07-25T18:30:00Z"
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        "inputStage" : {
                            "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                            "keyPattern" : {
                                "Host" : -1,
                                "SiteType" : -1
                            },
                            "indexName" : "Host_-1_SiteType_-1",
                            "isMultiKey" : false,
                            "direction" : "forward",
                            "indexBounds" : {
                                "Host" : [
                                    "[MaxKey, \"localhost\")",
                                    "(\"localhost\", MinKey]"
                                ],
                                "SiteType" : [
                                    "[MaxKey, MinKey]"
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "rejectedPlans" : [
                        {
                            "stage" : "FETCH",
                            "filter" : {
                                "$and" : [
                                    {
                                        "SiteType" : {
                                            "$exists" : true
                                        }
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "$or" : [
                                            {
                                                "$and" : [
                                                    {
                                                        "LifeTime" : {
                                                            "$eq" : 0
                                                        }
                                                    },
                                                    {
                                                        "Extension" : {
                                                            "$in" : [
                                                                "chrome_0",
                                                                "firefox_0"
                                                            ]
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                ]
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "LifeTime" : {
                                                    "$gt" : 1000
                                                }
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    }
                                ]
                            },
                            "inputStage" : {
                                "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                                "keyPattern" : {
                                    "VisitTime" : -1,
                                    "AccountId" : -1,
                                    "Host" : -1,
                                    "SiteType" : -1,
                                    "Extension" : -1,
                                    "LifeTime" : -1
                                },
                                "indexName" : "VisitTime_-1_AccountId_-1_Host_-1_SiteType_-1_Extension_-1_LifeTime_-1",
                                "isMultiKey" : false,
                                "direction" : "forward",
                                "indexBounds" : {
                                    "VisitTime" : [
                                        "[new Date(1437849000000), new Date(1406313000000)]"
                                    ],
                                    "AccountId" : [
                                        "[\"accID\", \"accID\"]"
                                    ],
                                    "Host" : [
                                        "[MaxKey, \"localhost\")",
                                        "(\"localhost\", MinKey]"
                                    ],
                                    "SiteType" : [
                                        "[MaxKey, MinKey]"
                                    ],
                                    "Extension" : [
                                        "[MaxKey, MinKey]"
                                    ],
                                    "LifeTime" : [
                                        "[MaxKey, MinKey]"
                                    ]
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "$group" : {
                "_id" : "$Host",
                "Count" : {
                    "$sum" : {
                        "$const" : 1
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "$sort" : {
                "sortKey" : {
                    "Count" : -1
                },
                "limit" : 5
            }
        },
        {
            "$project" : {
                "_id" : false,
                "Host" : "$_id",
                "TotalVisit" : "$Count"
            }
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Comment: No there is not a way to specifiy hint. Is `$match` your first pipeline stage? is there an appropraiate index that can be chosen based on the conditions in that statement? You don't show the query you are performing here or the "wrong index" that is being chosen or the "right one" you think should be chosen.

Comment: As a very brief observation, I would have throught the frequency of "AccountId" would be considerably less than "VisitTime", yet it is the first element in that compound index. You are in fact selecting what is likely a very large sample of "VisitTime". The Other index is the one being chosen, correct? Can you also include the explain output?

Comment: Hi @BlakesSeven, I've just updated my question with explain output and sample document. Please take a look, where I am doing wrong?

Comment: Much like I said earlier. The explain is showing that the "Host_-1_SiteType_-1" index is being selected. But the main reason the other index is not being selected is because the keys are not optimally ordered. A better approach would be: "AccountId_-1_Host_-1_VisitTime_-1_Extension_-1_LifeTime_-1_SiteType_-1", allowing the things that are likely to "filter more" to be declared first, with of course the key you only check `$exists` on being right at the end. Possibly even moving "VisitTime" back further as that is going to be the most granular item in the index.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Index definition can be very subjective, and not something you just idly say "index this stuff" and then hope for the best. It actually requires some thought about the search process to which it applies.

Your query here appears to be made up of these main elements, which are mostly the "Account" and "Lifetime" values. Sure there are other things in there like the "VisitTime" notably, but taking the old library and card index analogy then think about the process.

So when you walk through the library door you are presented with two card index systems:

1. Contains the books in the libary by the date they were authored, allowing you to get a selection of the cards pointing to the books based on the date
2. Contains the names of the authors of the books and there locations in the library.

Now considering that you know you want to look for books from an author written in the last 10 years, then which index system do you pick? So do you look through the dates of 10 years and look for the author contained within? Or do you rather first look up the author, and then narrow down to which books have been written in the last 10 years?

Chances are that the last 10 years has a lot more content that just that from a single author. Therefore 2 is the better choice because once you have all books for that author, then going through the cards to find those within 10 years should be a much smaller task.

This is why the order of keys in an index is important to the query patterns you are using. Clearly "Account" should be the thing that narrows the selection the most and then other details to help further narrow that down.

Anything that puts something like a "VisitTime" before that, means you need to sift through all of the things you likely don't want within that period before you actually get to the things you need.

Ordering is important, and you need to always consider that with index design.

Comment: Hi @blakes-seven I've tried  different order of index fields, and it seems that `Host_-1_SiteType_-1` is the most powerful index.It does not matter what I create as index, it always taking that index.

Comment: @AnkitSarkar As I have already stated, your explain output differs to your opionion. The index being chosen **is** "Host_-1_SiteType_-1", and therefore the one giving you the poor performance. The main summary of the response here is "Account" is what you need in order to narrow down the results to an acceptable query speed.

Comment: As per your suggestions, I've dropped all of the indexes and recreated them. Now my indexes are: `AccountId : -1,SiteType : -1,Host : -1,VisitTime : -1` , `Host_-1_SiteType_-1` , `AccountId : -1,SiteType : -1,Extension : -1, Host : -1, LifeTime : -1, VisitTime : -1`. and no 3 is now working :)  Thank you @blake-seven!

Comment: @AnkitSarkar As I said "Account first" is the key here. Don't forget to [accept](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) the answer that helped and also upvote if you already have not. Helps other know what was useful to you.

Answer (score 34):

**2019 answer**

**From MongoDB version 3.6**

From the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/aggregate/#hint-an-index), you can add hint with aggregation in the following manner:

```
db.collection.aggregate(pipeline, {hint: "index_name"})
```

If you want to see explain just add explain as you would without `hint`

Answer (score 1):

As @blake-seven mentioned earlier, to create an effective index on a huge collection, always keep in mind which fields are mostly used to narrow down your match condition. So I think twice before recreated them. As suggested I've put "AccountId" as first preference and after that "SiteType"(because "Category" wise search is more effective) after that "Extension"(you can think this field as "Sub Category") and "Host" is using to narrow number of returned docs further. that's it!

So , `AccountId : -1,SiteType : -1,Extension : -1, Host : -1, LifeTime : -1, VisitTime : -1` is my ultimate index.