# mongo sort before match in aggregation

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, query-planner

Given a collection of a few million documents that look like:

```
{
    organization: ObjectId("6a55b2f1aae2fe0ddd525828"),
    updated_on: 2019-04-18 14:08:48.781Z
}
```

and 2 indices, on both keys {organization: 1} and {updated_on: 1}

The following query takes ages to return:

```
db.getCollection('sessions').aggregate([
        {
                "$match" : {
                        "organization" : ObjectId("5a55b2f1aae2fe0ddd525827"),
                }
        },
        {
                "$sort" : {
                        "updated_on" : 1
                }
        }
])
```

One thing to note is, the result is 0 matches. Upon further investigation, the planner in explain() actually returns the following:

```
{
    "stage" : "FETCH",
    "filter" : {
        "organization" : {
            "$eq" : ObjectId("5a55b2f1aae2fe0ddd525827")
        }
    },
    "inputStage" : {
        "stage" : "IXSCAN",
        "keyPattern" : {
            "updated_on" : 1.0
        },
        "indexName" : "updated_on_1",
        "isMultiKey" : false,
        "multiKeyPaths" : {
            "updated_on" : []
        },
        "isUnique" : false,
        "isSparse" : false,
        "isPartial" : false,
        "indexVersion" : 2,
        "direction" : "forward",
        "indexBounds" : {
            "updated_on" : [ 
                "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

- Why would Mongo combine these into one stage and decide to to sort ALL documents BEFORE filtering?
- How can I prevent that?

Comment: You can tell MongoDB use specific index [https://stackoverflow.com/a/57092149/3710490](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57092149/3710490)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why would Mongo combine these into one stage and decide to to sort ALL
>   documents BEFORE filtering? How can I prevent that?

The sort *does* happen after the match stage. The query plan *doesn't* show the SORT stage - that is because there is an index on the sort key `updated_on`. If you remove the index on the `updated_on` field you *will* see a SORT stage in the query plan (and it will be an in-memory sort).

See [Explain Results - sort stage](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/explain-results/#sort-stage).

*Some Ideas:*

(i) You can use a compound index, instead of a two single field indexes:

```
{ organization: 1, updated_on: 1 }
```

It will work fine. See this topic on [Sort and Non-prefix Subset of an Index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/sort-results-with-indexes/#sort-and-non-prefix-subset-of-an-index).

(ii) Also, instead of an aggregation, a `find()` query can do the same job:

```
db.test.find( { organization : ObjectId("5a55b2f1aae2fe0ddd525827") } ).sort( { updated_on: 1 } )
```

NOTE: Do verify with `explain()` and see how they perform. Also, try using the `executionStats` mode.

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB will use the index on to `$sort` because it's a heavy operation even if matching before will limit the result to be sorted,

You can either force using the index for `$match`:

```js
db.collection.aggregate(pipeline, {hint: "index_name"})
```

Or create a better index to solve both problems, see more informations [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/sort-results-with-indexes/)

```js
db.collection.createIndex({organization: 1, updated_on:1}, {background: true})
```