# documentdb aggregate query not using index

Tags: mongodb, aws-documentdb

I am trying to find the max of a value in a range of dates. The aggregate query I use has a match on indexed column _id. But the query takes too long and the explain plan tells me its going of a COLLSCAN and not an index scan. Can you please suggest why it wont make use of the index on _id?

Would it help if I created another index on colId?

```
    {$match:{_id:{ $regex: 'regex'}}},
    {$match:{$and:[{"colId":'DATA'}]}},
    {$unwind:"$data"},
    {$match:{$and:[{"data.time":{$gte:ISODate("xyz"),$lte:ISODate("zyx")}}]}},
    {$match:{$and: [{ "data.col": { $exists: true}}] }},
    {$group:{_id:"$data.time",maxCol:{$max:"$data.col"}}} ,
    {$sort:{"maxCol":-1,_id:-1}},
    {$limit:1}
    ])
```

Explain plan snippet:

```
                "winningPlan" : {
                        "stage" : "LIMIT_SKIP",
                        "inputStage" : {
                                "stage" : "SORT",
                                "sortPattern" : {
                                        "_id" : -1,
                                        "maxCol" : -1
                                },
                                "inputStage" : {
                                        "stage" : "SUBSCAN",
                                        "inputStage" : {
                                                "stage" : "HASH_AGGREGATE",
                                                "inputStage" : {
                                                        "stage" : "SUBSCAN",
                                                        "inputStage" : {
                                                                "stage" : "PROJECTION",
                                                                "inputStage" : {
                                                                        "stage" : "COLLSCAN"
                                                                }
                                                        }
                                                }
                                        }
                                }
                        }
```

This is on DocumentDB (mongo4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DocumentDB does not seem to support index scan automatically when there is a regular expression match involved in the indexed column. [Document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/functional-differences.html#functional-differences.regex-indexing) suggests that we use hints to nudge AWS to use those indexes (wonder why the spoon-feeding).

`db.collection.aggregate([all_your_filters], {hint: {_id: 1}});`

But in my case adding the hint threw errors because it did not like me using non-capturing groups (?:x) in my regex. So I had to remove groups from my regex for the hints to work.

Answer (score 0):

I think regular expression cannot use indexes. `$match` works also on array, try this one:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   {
      $match: {
         "colId": 'DATA',
         "data.time": { $gte: ISODate("xyz"), $lte: ISODate("zyx") },
         "data.col": { $exists: true }
      }
   },
   { $match: { _id: { $regex: 'regex' } } },
   { $unwind: "$data" },
   { $group: { _id: "$data.time", maxCol: { $max: "$data.col" } } },
   { $sort: { "maxCol": -1, _id: -1 } },
   { $limit: 1 }
])
```

As consequence put an index on `{colId: 1, "data.time": 1}` or `{colId: 1, "data.time": 1, "data.col": 1}`

Comment: Thank you. Yes it has used index when I replace regex with a normal match condition. Looks like index scan doesn't work with regex. I will rewrite this query.

Comment: Just checked the [documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/#index-use), it should use the index also for `$regex`. I assume the index is not used, because `_id` field is a `ObjectId` rather than a string.

Comment: I dont think documentdb has implemented it in this manner. [docdb](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/functional-differences.html#functional-differences.regex-indexing) says we need to use hints. But hints dont work too well with aggregation. Maybe I should have stuck to MongoDB. Similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31633871/how-to-use-hint-in-mongodb-aggregation-query)